# How to plot regression predicted data in 3-D contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, mplot3d

I'm trying to plot the predicted mean data from Gaussian process regression into a 3-D contour. I've followed [Plot 3D Contour from an Image using extent with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817110/plot-3d-contour-from-an-image-using-extent-with-matplotlib)
 and [mplot3d example code: contour3d_demo3.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html) threads. Following is my code:

```js
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

x_train = np.array([[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]])
y_train = np.array([[200,321,417]])

xvalues = np.array([0,1,2,3])
yvalues = np.array([0,1,2,3])

a,b = np.meshgrid(xvalues,yvalues)
positions = np.vstack([a.ravel(), b.ravel()])
x_test = (np.array(positions)).T

kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10)

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)

gp.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred_test = gp.predict(x_test)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
x=y=np.arange(0,3,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = y_pred_test
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
plt.show()
```

After running the above code, I get following error on console:

[image]

I want x and y-axis as 2-D plane and the predicted values on the z-axis.The [sample plot](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=3-d%20contour%20plot&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw8tiQg_vaAhUFH5QKHZdXAbkQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=959#imgrc=ZlEwnnFk3nr40M:) is as follows:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you've mentioned comes from your `y_train`, which might be a typo. It should be:

> y_train_ : array-like, shape = (n_samples, [n_output_dims])

According to your `x_train`, you have 3 samples. So your `y_train` should have shape `(3, 1)` rather than `(1, 3)`.

You also have other bugs in the plotting part:

1. `add_subplot` should have a position before `projection = '3d'`.
2. `Z` should have the same shape as `X` and `Y` for contour plot.
3. Because of 2, your `x` and `y` should match `xvalues` and `yvalues`.

Taken together, you might need to make the following changes:

```
...

y_train = np.array([200,321,417])

...

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x=y=np.arange(0,4,1)
...
Z = y_pred_test.reshape(X.shape)

...
```

Just to mention two things:

1. The plot you will get after these changes won't match the figure you've shown. The figure in your question is a surface plot instead of a contour plot. You can use `ax.plot_surface` to get that type of plot.
2. I think you've already know this. But just in case, your plot won't be as smooth as your sample plot since your `np.meshgrid` is sparse.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. Inside the surface plot, I need to give some color differentiation, for example, red color for high data, blue for lowest, and greenish/yellowish for medium data. How can I do it? Any idea?

Comment: @santobedi You can start from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/whats_new_99_mplot3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-whats-new-99-mplot3d-py) or [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-surface3d-py).